# Return multiple paragraph tags from php function

Tags: php, function, return

Hello I've got the following function:

```
function getProductInformation($productArr, $productNumber){

for ($i=0; $i < count($productArr[0]); $i++) { 
    $products[] = $productArr[0][$i];
}
for ($i=0; $i < count($productArr[1]); $i++) { 
    $sizes[] = $productArr[1][$i];
}
for ($i=0; $i < count($productArr[2]); $i++) { 
    $prices[] = $productArr[2][$i];
}

?><p><?php
return $products[$productNumber] . " " . $sizes[$productNumber] . " " . $prices[$productNumber];
?></p><?php
}
```

If i echo the function with an array and a number as params it will return the following:

```
<p>product size price</p>
```

Instead of the function only returning one paragraph i would like the result to look like this

```
<p>product</p> <p>size</p> <p>price</p>
```

All help appreciated!

Comment: Learn the basics first, I don't think you understand what a function is: You can't close the PHP tag, and reopen it mid-way through a function definition. You just can't

Comment: Of course you can close PHP inside a function declaration. But this counts as `echo`, not a string that can be used i.e. in `return`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include HTML tags in strings:

```
function getProductInformation($productArr, $productNumber){

    $products = array_values($productArr[0]);
    $sizes = array_values($productArr[1]);
    $prices = array_values($productArr[2]);

    return "<p>" . $products[$productNumber] . "</p> <p>" . $sizes[$productNumber] . "</p> <p>" . $prices[$productNumber] . "</p>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking too much about breaking in and out of php. But this made it!